# How can system log/save All Assert statement messages?

Tags: java, logging, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, assert

I want to print value of assert statement in log file which are written in code statements as under :

Example: Assert.assertTrue(false,"Message");

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
e.printStackTrace( new PrintWriter(writer,true ));
 System.out.println("exeption stack is :\n"+writer.toString());
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can log all assertion errors, however after one of these fails, it is usually best to shutdown, rather than continue.

You can print the values in the expression by including them in the message.

e.g.

```
assert length >= 0 : "Length was " + length;
```

Comment: How can I do same with java. For example i want to log "assertTrue(true,selenium.isTextPresent("Selenium Wiki"));"  I want to print or save "Selenium Wiki". How actually it is possible?